# How to override products saveAction and editAction function in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php

I want to override save and edit function from ProductControll.php page.

While saving product want to override function.

Comment: why -1?????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets create a small module for overriding the product controller

**Step 1:- Create YourPackageName_Adminhtml.xml file at app/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourPackageName_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        <YourPackageName_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2:- Create module’s config.xml file at app/code/local/YourPackageName/Adminhtml/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourPackageName_Adminhtml>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        </YourPackageName_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <yourpackagename_adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">YourPackageName_Adminhtml</yourpackagename_adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

**Step 3:- Create ProductController.php controller file at app/code/local/YourPackageName/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php**

```
<?php
include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php");
class YourPackageName_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{
    public function editAction()
    {
        // your custom logic for editAction comes here
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        // your custom logic for saveAction comes here
    }
}
?>
```

Clear the cache and refresh and you have done.

Comment: still it is taking core file

Comment: show me your code

Comment: app\code\local\Product\Adminhtml\etc\config.xml  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Product_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Product_Adminhtml>
    </modules>    
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <product_adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">Product_Adminhtml</product_adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>    
</config>

Comment: i mean all three files code. not just file name

Comment: app\etc\modules\Product_Adminhtml.xml  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Product_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Product_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>  app\code\local\Product\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog  include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php");
class Product_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{
    /**
     * Save product action
     */
    public function saveAction()
    { echo "local new save"; exit; }

Comment: I have done the same way

Comment: I have made some modification in your folder structure i.e  app\code\local\Mage\Products\etc\config.xml  app\etc\modules\Mage_Products.xml  app\code\local\Mage\Products\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php

Comment: I have put your code as it is - The only change I have made is the  folder structure.